# Attempting to use _remap to create page controller

Tags: codeigniter

I'm trying to create a default page controller for a site with urls like http://www.example.com/about. So, if there isn't an 'about' controller, then go looking for a page with that url string in the database.

I've set the 404_override to my 'page' controller and am using the _remap() function to determine where to go next, either load the homepage (the page controller's index() method) or load a page.

However, as it stands right now if I use a different controller (product, in this case) with a method in the path (http://www.example.com/product/widget, which doesn't exist) I am being served the index() method of the page controller.

I thought the problem comes from the way I'm checking if the requested page is the homepage in my _remap() so I added an echo to the beginning of my remap to see if it mattered.  The _remap() doesn't appear to be called. Instead, in attempting to handle the 404_override CI just shows the index method.

Any ideas how I can accomplish this more effectively?

```
    public function _remap($method)
{
    echo 'Method '.$method;
    if($this->uri->segment(1) == null)
    {
        // $this->index();
    } else {
        $this->view();
    };
}
```

Comment: This CI issue seems to re-affirm that using _remap with 404_override isn't going to work out: https://github.com/EllisLab/CodeIgniter/issues/1062

Answer (score 0):

I seem to have found a workable solution in this blog post: http://pinoytech.org/blog/post/codeigniter-route-everything-except-these-controllers

Using a regular expression in the route definition allows for other controllers (product, order, etc.) to be ignored while still sending everything else to the page controller.

```
$route['^(?!product|order|misc_controller)\S*'] = "page/$1";
```

Haven't tested it out just yet, but as far as I can tell it should work swimmingly.